# to write on google spread sheet after form submit with php and google library

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I want to update my google spread sheet after my form submit with php

I have used library "google-api-php-client"

My code for that is below to authentication with OAuth2 authentication,

```
private function authenticate()
    {
        /*
         * Authentication using the library 'google-api-php-client' which uses 'Oauth2'.
         */
        require 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';
        $scopes = array('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');
        $pri_key = file_get_contents(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/My Project service account.p12');
        $credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
           'CLIENT_ID', #google dev console email
           $scopes,
           $pri_key
        );

        $this->client = new Google_Client();
        $this->client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
        if ($this->client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $this->client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
        }

        $tokenData = json_decode($this->client->getAccessToken());
        $this->accessToken = $tokenData->access_token;
    }
```

Here I have create one service account and web application in my gmail account and from there above I have used client Id and p12 file, but it gives me below error,

```
Google_Auth_Exception
IT WAS THROWN IN
\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php on line 363

MESSAGE
Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{
"error" : "invalid_grant",
"error_description" : "Invalid JWT Signature."
}'
```

Is there any thing missing from me in this or follow wrong flow ???

Comment: you should read this document https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app

Comment: ok, thanks, let me go through this document

Comment: I have refer the above given document, but check my setting as well , I am still on same error\

Comment: is there any credential missing or google project and service account creatation problem

Comment: I have resolve above error by using this url : https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

Comment: but when ever I read data from spread sheet with method "getRows" it gives me error response like : Error in Google Request

Comment: can you give me solution for this ???